# How to allocate core to a process not process to core?

Tags: process, parallel-processing, processor, cpu-cores

it is easy to allocate a process to particular core , but how to make sure only that process should run on that  particular core or cores.Rest processes can run on other cores. Please help me in this.

Comment: On Linux, maybe give it realtime priority as well as using `taskset` to pin it to a core.  That might or might not be acceptable, depending on what kind of process, and what kind of system.

Comment: i want to give  a core/cores  exclusively  to a particular process. No other process run on that.

Comment: Someone on another question suggested setting the affinity of all *other* processes to exclude that core.  That might prevent other threads from dirtying the cache on that core, compared to using realtime prio to make sure it always got the core.

Comment: thanks peter, ya we can do that ,  but  anyhow it is affinity so if cores are not free then it can use our core also.

Comment: i think , we can do this, like what you told "affinity", i got this from other  question on this platform only.                1   Add the parameter isolcpus=[cpu_number] to the Linux kernel command line form the boot loader during boot. This will instruct the Linux scheduler to no run any regular tasks on that CPU unless specifically requested using cpu affinity.

     2   Use IRQ affinity to set other CPUs to handle all interrupts so that your isolated CPU will not received any interrupt.

     3  Use CPU affinity to fix your specific task to the isolated CPU.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that boot option existed.  If it works, you should write that comment as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

i got answer from similar question

1. Add the parameter isolcpus=[cpu_number] to the Linux kernel command line form the boot loader during boot. This will instruct the Linux scheduler to no run any regular tasks on that CPU unless specifically requested using cpu affinity.
2. Use IRQ affinity to set other CPUs to handle all interrupts so that your isolated CPU will not received any interrupt.
3. Use CPU affinity to fix your specific task to the isolated CPU